# Java: Program is not counting occurrences of element inside arraylist

Tags: java

I am making a program that will count the occurrences of "red" and "blue" cars when user inputs a string of the colours of the cars passing by on one line.

I have tried to implement an arraylist and counter but it does not seem to be working. I would just like to to know what am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     String red = "red";
     String blue = "blue";
     int red_count =  0;
     int blue_count =  0;
     System.out.println("Cars: ");
     String x = scanner.nextLine();

     ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
     arr.add(x);

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        String c = arr.get(i);
        if (c.equals("red")) {
            red_count = red_count + 1;
        }
        if (c.equals("blue")) {
            blue_count = blue_count + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("red: " + red_count);
        System.out.println("blue: " + blue_count);
     }
    }
   }
```

**Input:**
red green blue yellow

**Output:**

red: 0

blue: 0

Comment: you have to spllit the string currently you compare the whole string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your code:

```
 String x = scanner.nextLine();
```

You take 1 line of input, which (according to your post) is "red green blue yellow". When you add this to the list, you don't separate the words, so the list will only contain one element (your full input string), not 4. If you want to separate the words in the input, use `x.split("\\s")` and add all elements of the array to the list (or just use the array from that point on).

The second mistake is in your output: you have the `System.out.println()` statements within the loop, so it displays the red and blue car's count every time.

Comment: so I have to split the string up in order to get comparison of each element instead of whole string. Also the sytem.out.println was a very stupid mistake thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look it will work as per your requirement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String red = "red";
        String blue = "blue";
        System.out.println("Cars: ");
        String x = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] brr = x.split(" ");

        Map<String, Long> collect = Arrays.stream(brr)
                .filter(a->a.equals(red)||a.equals(blue))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
       
        System.out.println(collect);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add(x);
```

to

```
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));
```

You need to split the line by space.

Entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String red = "red";
        String blue = "blue";
        int red_count =  0;
        int blue_count =  0;
        System.out.println("Cars: ");
        String x = scanner.nextLine();

        List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            String c = arr.get(i);
            if (c.equals("red")) {
                red_count = red_count + 1;
            }
            if (c.equals("blue")) {
                blue_count = blue_count + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("red: " + red_count);
        System.out.println("blue: " + blue_count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use HashMap for these kinds of problems to find occurrences.

This solves all in one,

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

cars.put(x, (cars.get(x) != null) ? cars.get(x) + 1 : 1);


System.out.println("Red cars: " + cars.get("red"));
System.out.println("Blue cars: " + cars.get("blue"));
```

For more information check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp).